# Import an image webpack, reactjs + typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Have a react js project with typescript.

I have this in one project (generated with official reactjs starter + typescript):

```
import logo from './ty.png';
...
<img style={{height: "25px"}} src={logo} alt="Logo" />
```

[image]
Works

In an other project I have exactly the same. But it's built from http://demo.g-axon.com/jumbo-react-flat/#/app/dashboard/default

It's not working there. The `src` is missing.

[image]

What can be wrong? Webpack config? Tsconfig? What shall I look for?

```
import * as React from 'react';

import logo from './ty.png'

const App = ({  }) => {
  return (
    <img src={logo}/>
  )}
```

Comment: can you share the code snippet where you are facing the issue and whats the exact error you are getting

Comment: @warl0ck I'm not getting any error. The src is just missing. I've attached two screenshots.

Comment: Can you share the code snippet where you are rendering it, from final html wont be able to help

Comment: @warl0ck. Question updated with code snippet.

Comment: i think either Logo is undefined or this is not the component getting rendered as if you see you are not passing alt and style its still in the DOM